Energy Storage and Rapid Dissipation
I am tasked to figure out ways of storing potential energy, around 12000 Joules, to be released almost instantly in form of kinetic energy in a creative way. I tried using springs and hydraulic accumulators but it was too basic. I was thinking of using solenoids to do this. Is this even possible?
The goal is to store energy as creatively as possible, however the energy stored must be able to be released quickly. Are there other ways to approach this?

Let's see, 12,000 joules if released over a second would be 12,000 watts.  If released from a bank of capacitors, charged to 100 volts, that would be 120 amps. That is not unreasonable.  The problem is to turn it into useful kinetic energy.  If you ran 120 amps through a coil, you could get a substantial magnetic field.  This question says a coil with 100 amps could pick up 6283 newtons from 100 mm away. (Sorry, I'm too lazy to look up the details.)  But we are talking about 120 amps so that would be (about) 9000 newtons (increasing with square of current).
Releasing kinetic energy, however, is more of a problem.  The magnetic field drops off with the square of distance.  If the pull is 9000 newtons at 100 mm, it would be 2300 newtons at 200 mm.  It also increased when the distance gets smaller so at 50 mm, the force would be 36,000 newtons.
This might be workable, if you set a big honking (that's a technical term for magnetic devices) solenoid, you could pull with a starting force of 2300 newtons, increasing with the (decreasing) square of distance until, say you stopped at 50 mm with a force of 36,000. My hand-waving guesstimate is that would be an average of 9200 newtons for 0.150 meters for 1380 joules.  This is where my knowledge of such things gets shaky, as the distance goes to zero, the force goes to infinity so if we take it all the way to 9 mm, the max force would be 1,120,000 newtons. The energy would be 61,000 newtons over 0.191 meters or (about) 12,000 joules. (Think of the loud snap when that thing goes off.)
The bad news is there are annoying things about discharging capacitors quickly into an inductor and resistance in the coils.  Since this is only going for a second, we can get away with much thinner wires for the coil than if it were for continuous use.  Unfortunately, the thinner the wires, the higher the resistance so the slower the discharge.  When a magnetic field increases quickly, it pushes back on increasing current as if it were a resistance.  (I knew how to solve problems like that no more than many years ago.)  If you were going to actually build such a thing, you would need to take that into account.

Thanks for the explanation!

Does it need to be practical?  Filling a balloon with something combustible and then igniting it could be a fun, albeit maybe a bit unsafe approach.

No I don't think it needs to be practical, we are kind of in a brainstorming phase. Can you elaborate more on the balloon combustion idea?
